# bootstrap navbar not active

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this navbar and I cannot set an item to active - I have no idea why. Can someone explain this to me?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">payment transactions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">transaction notes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">slow transactions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you defined any style for active class

Comment: I thought bootstrap has these already in it?

Comment: just inspect it , if it doesnt have just add one

Comment: It already has style, because this happens when I apply some background-color to the active class - https://media.giphy.com/media/2tTkMgGpIEnEkr6GHD/giphy.gif